# Scale SVG object to fit window height

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Alright, I've dug and dug and dug, and tried numerous solutions, but I'm having some difficulty forcing my inline SVG artwork to scale to the browser window's height.

You can see a [live example up here](http://classicwfl.com/portrait.html) (note: the markup might be a little rough, just created the art & markup today).

Older browser compatibility isn't an issue, but I want to ensure I get consistent displays across mobile & desktop (which, of course, is a fresh pain all it's own with SVG).

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code here

Comment: If it's too big increase the viewBox size.

Comment: Apply the following to your svg height and width properties.

    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;

It will always auto scale to 100% height and width of your container or viewport.

Comment: Korgrue, that works great on desktop, but on mobile not so much (testing on Android with the latest Chrome browser).

Comment: May have gotten it to work "good enough" for every platform now. Just gotta test on other browsers.